# iOS What is the maximum count of users that can connect to a gamecenter match in a bluetooth session?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I couldn't find docs on this.  So simply, how many people can connect to a gamecenter bluetooth/wifi match? Is there a limit? Could 100 people easily join a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `GKMatchRequest` documentation:

> The maximum number of players may be no more than 4 for a peer-to-peer match and no more than 16 for a hosted match.

Comment: Can you please provide the helpful documentation..? It makes good impression of answer.

Comment: It's all in XCode, but here you go! http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GKMatchRequest_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This answer seems quite old. The linked documentation does not mention any limits anymore. I wonder if there are any limits applied by Apple at all. Naturally, there will be a "playable" kind of limit. Did anyone try more than 10 players?